# Seduction Assassin

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class

Is there a prestige class or alternate class or archetype in Pathfinder made specifically for a seduction based assassin?

So far the closest thing I found was Ninja, but it's still lacking in the seduction part, while Bard on the other hand can be all about seduction yet lacks any type of lethality and Slayers don't appear to have any charisma based archetypes...

I also considered Bard going into the Assassin prestige class, but that would take too many levels to achieve.

Comment: What do you imagine *seduction* entailing beyond the Bluff skill and *charm* and *suggestion* spells?

Comment: Do you consider multiclassing?

Comment: Seduction would be more role playing based, you could play a bard or a class that would give you benefits to bluff and then create a character that utilizes bluff in combat as a feint to make their opponents flat footed.

Comment: Yes, I am considering multiclassing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### There are a few options, but none of them are an exact fit.

- The [Deadly Courtesan](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-vishkanyas/deadly-courtesan-rogue-vishkanya) rogue archetype trades some rogue talents & features for bardic song, specifically the Fascinate performance. You have to be a [Vishkanya](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-vishkanyas) to qualify, though.
- The [Enchanting Courtesan](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/enchanting-courtesan/) prestige class gives several abilities focused around casting enchantment spells covertly and with greater effect as well as some abilities to help you use poison. If you were envisioning stabbing people after seducing them then this prestige class is not for you, but if you're OK with poisoning or enthralling your targets then it's worth a look.
- The [Master Spy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/advanced-players-guide/master-spy) prestige class helps you deceive people, especially people who are trying to use divination spells on you. It also gives sneak attack and the assassin's death attack.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're looking to create an Assassin, I'm assuming you're set on either the Rogue or Rogue/Assassin build. Both of which have access to Rogue Talents, which offer a great variety of turning conversations in your favor by use of your character's charme:

- [Charmer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/charmer-ex)
- [Coax Information](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/coax-information-ex)
- [Convincing Lie](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/convincing-lie-ex)
- [False Friend](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-kitsune/kitsune-trickster-rogue-kitsune/false-friend-ex)
- [Honeyed Words](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/honeyed-words-ex)

Because of your assassin background, you may also want some "less passive" skills, in order to manipulate and obfuscate as much of your environment as possible. That will be aided by the following Rogue Talents:

- [Hard to Fool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/hard-to-fool-ex)
- [Innocent Facade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/innocent-facade-sp)
- [Obfuscate Story](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-kitsune/kitsune-trickster-rogue-kitsune/obfuscate-story-ex)
- [Steal the Story](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-kitsune/kitsune-trickster-rogue-kitsune/steal-the-story-ex)

Obviously, what you want to go with those is high Charisma to buff the respective skills as much as possible.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a character that can assassinate (i.e. kill things quickly), not an assassin specifically. But +1 for the list of rogue talents-- I have a seducer rogue myself and will look into these.

Comment: Actually I'm looking more for non Rogue stuff since I've played too many rogues recently, but If I can't find anything better I'll go back to Ninja or Rogue.

Comment: @Evil: The reason for my initial assumption is that the Rogue is really the only class who's feats and special abilities (such as Rogue Talents) are laid out for something like this, and for a system that treats social encounters with as little love as Pathfinder does ability-wise, I believe these abilities offer a lot, so the way I see it, you're likely going to have to at least dip into a class with Rogue Talents (or the Ninja). Of course, if you're willing to look beyond classes to achieve your goal, you may find the Succubus to be a race that has its very own take on a seductive assassin.

Comment: @TheThirdMan: Yeah the DM won't allow me to play an actual succubus, but  that would be perfect for what I'm looking for.